# How to authenticate users to multiple channels

Tags: javascript, php, pusher, pusher-js

I am building a php/javascript application which allows each individual user to connect to their private channel, e.g., private-channel.userID

The user is authenticated through the following authentication endpoints, see the code below.

However, after user is authenticated, it appears that they can also subscribe to other private-channel and send/receive messages.

For example, assume userID 100 should subscribe to private-channel.100. After it authenticates through the endpoints, he can also send messages to private-channel.200 or whatever the other private-channel.userID!!!

Anyway to allow user 100 to authenticate only to the private-channel.100 and not able to subscribe to other private-channels

I think something is wrong with the authentication endpoints, but could not figure out what.

Thanks much!

```
public function pusherAuth(Request $request){
    $pusher = new Pusher(
        config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key'),
        config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.secret'),
        config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.app_id'),
        config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.options')
    );
    $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
    // return $pusher->socket_auth($request->channel_name, $request->socket_id);
    //$channel = $request->channel_name;response()->json(
    // $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
    $auth = $pusher->socket_auth($request->channel_name, $request->socket_id);
    $jsn = json_decode($auth,true);
    // return response($auth)->header('Content-Type',"application/json");
    return response()->json($jsn);
    // re\turn ['auth' => $jsn->auth];
}
```

The php client code:

```
connectToPusher() {
    this.pusher = new Pusher(window.Config.pusherKey, {
        authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
        cluster: window.Config.pusherCluster,
        auth: {
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': window.Config.csrfToken
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: So the basic question is how to allow user 100 to access only channel-100, not channel-200 etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in PHP but from your code you seem to be authorizing any user to any channel, that's the problem.

On the server side you should check that the userId of the logged user in the system matches the channel name he's trying to subscribe to. Otherwise reject the connection.

Anyway, probably your issue is somewhere else too, why a user is trying to get into another user's channel?